# Javascript extract numbers and operators from string with negative values

Tags: javascript, split, expression

I have the next input: `8+9`

I wold like to extract the numbers and the operators in separate arrays, I have the next code:

```
const numbers = input.split(/\D/g).filter(Boolean);
console.log("numbersBeforeFilter:", numbers);
const op = input.split(/\d/g).filter(Boolean);
```

in numbers I have `["8", "9"]`

And in operators: `["+"]`

Which it's ok, but if I have for example the next expression: -7, I have the next result:

in numbers I have `["7"]`

And in operators: `["-"]`

Which is wrong because I must have -7 in the numbers array and the operator one empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can match a number including a leading `-` *if* the token is preceded by either the start of the string, or by another operator:

```js
const parse = str => str.match(/(?<=^|[-+*/])\-\d+|\d+|[-+*/]/g);
console.log(
  parse('8+9'),
  parse('-7'),
  parse('3*-5')
);
```

- `(?<=^|[-+*/])\-\d+` - Match a dash and digits preceded by

  - `^` - start of string, or by
  - `[-+*/]` - any of the characters `-+*/`
- `\d+` - Or match digits
- `[-+*/]` - Or match operators